# Using FTP Programs with Automatic Proxy Configuration URL

Tags: proxy, ftp, ftp-client, filezilla

I've literally searched the internet for the last 5 hours and I have tried every suggestion out there and I'm starting to wonder if what I want to do is simply not possible....

Most webservers only allow X simultaneous connections for uploading/downloading. I simply want to upload my many files faster, by connecting/uploading through various proxies. However, no program I can find has anything for automatic proxy configuration, and only for a specific proxy IP. I have an account with a proxy service that gives you a different IP address for every request/connection made through it. I can connect to this fine from any FTP program but it appears that the servers are confused when they see different IP's connecting, and there's no way to manually whitelist/authenticate them on the server side, so it simply closes all connections. I even have a list of IP addresses with port/user/pass that I am willing to use, but I can't figure out how to do anything other than use a specific proxy to upload/download from servers.... Is this even possible????

ANY HELP/INPUT IS GREATLY APPRECIATED!!